# Log failed IIS login (windows authentication)

Tags: c#, authentication, iis

In our application, we offer the use of Windows authentication. For this, the browser pops-up a window. When a user is logged in correctly, I can log this in the code after this:

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) c.Response.Redirect(General.PathPrefix() + "Default.aspx");
```

My question is, how can I log a user not getting authenticated, all code seems to stop when the login fails, and I get a 401 response.

Answer (score 0):

You can log this error in the `Global.asax` file using the code below

```
public class CoolMvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        //check here if this exception is an unauthorized access error, if so
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Redirect("/not_loggedin");
    }
}
```

Also you can achieve this by using filters and assert there if the error is unauthorized access and follow the same logic.

Comment: When debugging, the code never seems to enter this function.